# looking for a combinatorial interpretation

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

given positive integers $n,m$ does the fraction

$$
\frac{(nm)!}{n!^mm!}
$$

count something? Namely does it correspond to the number of possibilities to do something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This counts the number of partions of $nm$ items into $m$ groups of $n$ items.

$$\frac{(nm)!}{(n!)^m}=\binom{nm}{n,n,\dots,n}$$

is the number of ordered partitions of $nm$ elements into $m$ sets of $n$ elements. Dividing by $m!$ the counts unordered partitions of this sort.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it counts in how many ways that you can divide mn-elements set into m sets each with n elements.
For example we have got mn kids and they want to buy candies. But in the shop could be only n childs together (childrens are in n-elements groups). In how many ways childrens can be in the queue to the shop?

Comment: This is mostly right, but the queuing example is confusing, because a queue is ordered, and this expression counts un-ordered partitions of the set. It might be a better example to say splitting up $nm$ kids into $m$ teams of $n$ kids each...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a simple possibility to show this by counting the cosets of certain symmetric groups.

Consider the symmetric group of $n$ elements $S_n$. Since $S_n ≀ S_m$ can obviously interpreted as a subgroup of $S_{nm}$, you see that $\frac{(nm)!}{n!^m m!}$ is the number of cosets of $S_n ≀ S_m$ in $S_{nm}$.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I don't know what does the symbol $S_n $ vertical $\sim$ $S_n$ mean??

Comment: It's the wreath product. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product